# Format (a float to string with no decimals) in nim

Tags: nim-lang

I have a float, say `14.55e9` and I want to stringify it to `"14550000000"` the most nimic, clean and performant way as possible.

For now I only could find something based on slicing:
`$myFloat[0..$myFloat.find('.')]`

The `formatFloat` method from `strutils` outputs `"14550000000.0"` if you ask for `precision=0`

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
import json, math
var intvalue = int(math.floor( 14.55));
echo  %*(intvalue);
```

EDIT: 
Sorry i posted some javascript code. Math is lowercase in Nim
 and JSON.stringify was from javascript

Comment: like this ?
https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/M7cgv6hEwSvY309HITexJIOrLLFIITOvpCwxpzRVwVbBFyiml5aTn1@koWBoomdqqmnNBVKtV1xSlJmXnplWqQFTjSmDpBmiV9P6/38A
it doesn't build :( :(

Comment: yes, sorry it was an accident. use Math as lowercase.

Comment: I did what I could to make it build, resulting in this: https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/M7cgv6hEIas4P09HITexJENHobikqLQkM6eYqyyxSCEzr6QsMac0VcEWLKuXlpOfX6RhaKJnaqppzZWanJGvoALSrJeXWu7llpOfWKIB04JLHtkITev//wE you'll note that the output still is `14.0` and not `14`

Comment: aaah, ok but sorry, I forgot to specify that my integers will not fit the `int` type, so it has to be directly formatted from the float value, not going through an int cast, of course I already thought of that, it would be too easy :) (because the exponential range of float, it can go weeeell beyond 2 billion very quickly)